# environment variables confuse

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

I use win10 and have python3.5 interpreter in my disk:E.
and something strange happened.I create two environment in my computer.

[image]

Then i made a little test script in pycharm:
[image]

It showed None.

however,when i open the python shell and do the same thing,it successed.

[image]

why?

Comment: Try to print(os.environ.get('MAIL_USERNAME')) in python shell and lets see what you get?

Comment: Also, how many Python versions do you have installed in your computer? and please include the header of your Python Shell to see what Python version are you running ?

Comment: solved.maybe i open pycharm before i write environment variables .when i reopen pycharm,everything is ok